# Query to Match a Polygon that contains a Point

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, geojson

The documents in my mongodb collection look like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5562d6831683523f449e7d85")
"geometry" : {
"type" : "Polygon",
"coordinates" : 
    [[
    [-122.4,37.81],
    [-132.9, 39.9],
    [-122.28, 37.80],
    [-124.18, 39.81]
    ]]
}}
```

I have a point (lat long pair), which I'll call `x` and `y`.  I need to see if the coordinates of the document create a polygon such that these coordinates are inside that polygon.

So, of course I need to compute the line describing each edge of the polygon, etc., and  then see if the coordinates of the point are within that.  However, for now, let's just assume we want to query documents that have `x` and `y` within the maximum and  minimum lat long values of the entire array.

Here is how I tried to query this:

```
db.<collection-name>.find(
    {'geometry.coordinates':
        {$elemMatch:
            {
                [{$gt:-122.1}, {$lt:-122.0 }], [{$gt: 37.89 },{$lt: 37.91}]
            }
        }
    }
)
```

however, the result is: `Unexpected token [`.  I tried to follow the example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-array/).

How do I  query an array like this, where there are conditions on each element of  the array in the document?   thanks.

Comment: I removed the "mysql" tag because the question explicitly refers to MongoDB.

Comment: Threre are better ways to find a point inside a Polygon stored in your collection. However your document structure ( cannot have "two" keys called "type" ) and coodinates map is not valid for GeoJSON. Did you trim this down and remove some of the details from the document? Please check and edit with a valid document you have.

Comment: Still not valid, which is why I am trying to **help** you. A "Polygon" must contain at least "four" points, with the last point closing the loop. Also the correct notation is `[[ [lon,lat], [lon,lat], [lon,lat], [lon,lat] ]]` with double brackets `[[` enclosing each pair. With valid data you do not need to try and match array elements within bounds.

Comment: @BlakesSeven:  _Thanks_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you seem to be trying to do by matching array elements is actually *"Finding a Polygon that contains a Point"*, which is why I changed your question title.

To accomplish this you are better off using the geoSpatail features of MongoDB rather than trying to work out the bounds yourself. With valid GeoJSON data the query is quite simple using the [**`$geoIntersects`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) operator.

To demonstrate, I'll first set up a collection, with some Polygon data:

```js
db.areas.insert([
    {
        "name": "San Jose",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [ -122.20916748046876, 37.13404537126446  ],
                [ -122.20916748046876, 37.496652341233364 ],
                [ -121.65710449218749, 37.496652341233364 ],
                [ -121.65710449218749, 37.13404537126446  ],
                [ -122.20916748046876, 37.13404537126446  ]
             ]]
         }
    },
    {
        "name": "San Franciso",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [ -122.73651123046874, 37.58811876638322 ],
                [ -122.73651123046874, 37.89219554724437 ],
                [ -122.28332519531249, 37.89219554724437 ],
                [ -122.28332519531249, 37.58811876638322 ],
                [ -122.73651123046874, 37.58811876638322 ]
            ]]
        }
    }
])
```

Then ( though not required for `$geoIntersects` specifically ) when working with geoSpatial data it is best to have an "index" defined. The one that makes sense for real GeoJSON locations is ["2dsphere"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/). The index is created on the field that contains the "root" of the GeoJSON data, which is in this case called "geometry":

```js
db.areas.createIndex({ "geometry": "2dsphere" })
```

Then all you need to do is supply a `.find()` query. I'm using the coordinates for "San Francisco city" here:

```js
db.areas.find({
    "geometry": {
        "$geoIntersects": {
             "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 
                    -122.45361328124999, 
                    37.76420119453823
                ]
             }
         }
    }
})
```

Which of course returns the "Polyon" defining the "San Franciso" area since that "Point" lies within that object.

```js
    {
        "name": "San Franciso",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [ -122.73651123046874, 37.58811876638322 ],
                [ -122.73651123046874, 37.89219554724437 ],
                [ -122.28332519531249, 37.89219554724437 ],
                [ -122.28332519531249, 37.58811876638322 ],
                [ -122.73651123046874, 37.58811876638322 ]
            ]]
        }
    }
```

That is all there is to finding whether your "Point" lies within a "Polygon" you have stored in your collection.

Also look at tools such as [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) and [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) (examples, not endorsements) in order to validate and visualise your data, which from your example does not provide a well formed Polygon.

Comment: Okay great.  Did not know there was a built-in for this.  Now, why is the indexing necessary?  This is not clear to me.  Also, why is it necessary when MongoDB already uses an `_id` for all of the documents?

Comment: @Sother The index is not required for this query, but sooner or later you will likely want to query for `$near` which does require the index. At any rate, an index on the field ( "geometry" here ) always speeds up searches. The `_id` is just a "Primary Key". It does not "aid" in searching on other fields.